# Android WebView Opens links in browser instead of app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I followed this tutorial: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/webview/android-webview-example/

Every time I click on a link in the webview, it takes me out of the webview and into a separate browser window. **How do I get all the links to open in the webview?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to implement `setWebViewClient(....)` like so.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
        }
});
```

Comment: I am getting the error, cannot resolve symbol WebViewClient

Comment: @KatieH for that you should `import android.webkit.WebViewClient;`

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much!!!!!! :))) One quick question, if you take a look at the tutorial, it requires the user to click a button to load the webview, do I have to do this? Can I make the webview load automatically with having to click the button? How can I do that?

Comment: Should I ask this in a separate stackoverflow question?

Comment: @KatieH Off course you can do it without any `Button click` just move all button `onClick(..)` code to `Activity onCreate(...)`.

Comment: before loadurl try this: myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());